# How to control file permissions with a Synology NAS that uses NFS for LAN file sharing

Tags: permissions, bind, nfs, nas

I need help modifying the file sharing system I have setup in my LAN.

Here is what I currently have:
[Sharing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MV6op.jpg)

I use my desktop to create, sort and catalog all of the media that I have.  That media is stored on ext4 internal SSDs.  That media is then copied to the Synology NAS to serve as a backup and a media source for all that I want to share.  LAN-side sharing is currently configured through NFS v3 in the NAS control panel.  Sharing through the NAS works as follows:

Media folder on the NAS -> NFS v3 sharing with specific LAN IP (IP of a specific computer, such as the HTPC), and specific file sharing permissions -> folders containing the media are mounted on each computer via /etc/fstab.  An example from one the HTPC is below:

> 192.168.1.149:/volume1/Music /home/USER/Music/Music-Share nfs auto,suid,dev,ro,exec,user,_netdev,x-gvfs-show 0 0

The sharing permissions set in the NAS control panel are the same as those specified in /etc/fstab for all three devices shown in the image above (HTPC, Music PC and my cell phone).  This works fine for me, because I do change or edit media on any of the three mentioned devices.

NFS is used to mount the NAS drives to my desktop, as well (with r/w/x permissions, of course).  This is where the file permissions issue comes about.  I have cannot maintain different file permissions for the same file that is saved on my desktop and on my NAS.

Here is an example:
A short video is uploaded to my desktop after recording, and the needed edits are made.  The file name of this video file is VIDEOFILE.mkv.  It is then uploaded to my NAS for sharing.  At a later time, I log into my NAS's admin user through Synology's remote connection service from a remote device to further edit the same video.  That video is saved to the NAS with the same file name.  After editing for a second time, I consider the video sharable with others through the WAN sharing user.  Now, I have two versions of VIDEOFILE.mkv and I would like to copy that second version of the video to my desktop.  To do this, I use Unison and instruct it to overwrite the older version of VIDEOFILE.mkv that is on my desktop with the newer version of the file that is on my NAS.
Getting Desktop/NAS syncing to work was a challenge, because I found that NFS v3 sharing doesn't allow different file permissions between the desktop and the NAS.  Editing file sharing permissions on the desktop effects sharing permissions for NAS' WAN user and editing file sharing permissions on the NAS overwrites file permissions on my desktop after syncing through Unison.  Because file permissions on the NAS needs to be maintained for the WAN sharing user, I'm finding that I need to give all shared desktop files read, write and execute permissions for the user, the group and everyone else on my desktop computer. i.e. the output of ls -ahl VIDEOFILE.mkv when checked from my desktop is:

> -rwxrwxrwx 1 USER GROUP 100k Jan 1 2023 VIDEOFILE.mkv

For now, this is tolerable, because I live alone.  No one else uses my desktop or is connected to my LAN.  However, I'd like to find a way to maintain different file permissions for the same file that is on my NAS and on my desktop, after syncing.  To use that same file as an example again, the desktop would have the following ls -ahl output:

> -rwxr-x--- 1 USER GROUP 100k Jan 1 2023 VIDEOFILE.mkv

while the NAS would still be able to maintain r/w/x permissions for the admin user and r/x permissions for the WAN user.

Is this possible with NFS v4?  If so, is there any documentation on the matter?  If not, do I need to use the bind mount option when I mount the NAS on my desktop?  If both are wrong, is there another way to solve this?